# SOAP Web service returning NullPointerException

Tags: java, web-services, soap

I have created a SOAP web service inside a dynamic web project in eclipse, it is working fine when called through local intranet, but when it is hosted on internet server it is returning `NullPointerException`. What can be the reason of this exception?

Comment: Probably you need to change the Web Service server address location

Comment: You have two servers, one that serves the web services (producer) and another that consumes them (consumer). Then, by your problem description I can just think that the consumer points to an invalid producer (which can be an invalid server ip address) or that there's no data to return from the producer.

Comment: No, that webservice is being consumed by an android app

Comment: I think your client and server both are in same domain - when you said local intranet. So , when the client in on a different domain, the URL of the wsdl is not accessible. you could possible check the wsdl url outside ur domian

Comment: When I am trying to hit some other webservice like of WCF, its working fine...